# Hostname based traffic routing to ips and ports

Tags: linux, php, security, apache2, groups

Need to figure out a safe setup that allows me to control traffic based on hostnames.

For example at the moment I am dealing with a small list of people on a small machine. Every one of this persons has an apache virtual host with php configured where they host their custom web pages.

My struggle comes when they start using "unreliable php plugins" on said virtual hosts. I've tried everything: disable_functions, suhosin, open_basedir, it's a mess.

What I need is total isolation. I want every one of these people on their own physical or virtual machine and me or main server that listens to port 80,443 to "route" traffic to specific ips and ports and minimize damage caused by a security breach.

What options do I have in terms of complexity and price?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a tip:

It sounds like you have multiple clients on a single server "apache / nginx" with "virtual host" in this particular case I recommend using Docker
with the use of "docker-compose" and you can make use of "[Networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers)" private and isolated at a minimal cost. (I feel that the priority for the moment will be to reduce costs)

In this way each client can build their own PHP modules, their own [PHP version](https://github.com/splitbrain/docker-phpfarm), each client can connect to their [own port and SSH server](https://github.com/jeroenpeeters/docker-ssh) separately so that they have access to modify their files , among many other utilities

And depending on the architecture you need, you can maintain a single database on the real machine (which is what I recommend for IOPS and kernel accesses) or you can also keep the databases isolated by client (beware. .. if they use INNODB and not MYISAM, the consumption of each MYSQL server can be triggered depending on the configuration of cache to ram)

I wish you success in your project